# How can I sum up the totals of groupings in views?

Tags: views, css-js-aggregation

I am trying to sum up my sales in my Commerce store by month.

I have created a view of completed payment transactions that is grouped by payment year (first grouping) and then payment month (second grouping).  The config looks like this:

[image: views config]

This gives output look like this:

[image: sales image]

Now what I'd like to do is sum up each month (the second grouping) to show the total sales for that month.  I think I can use aggregation for this but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the links I found for this kind of thing point towards [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator).  Apparently it allows you to "aggregate and group by column" ([source](https://www.drupal.org/node/2361413)).